# How can I implement a itemRenderer on my MenuBar in Flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe, itemrenderer, menubar

I'm trying to make a menubar with an itemrenderer of linkbuttons. How could I go by doing this? Here is what my code looks like so far, but I can't seem to get it working.

```
<mx:MenuBar id="menuBar" labelField="@label" dataProvider="{menus}" itemRenderer="mx.controls.LinkButton">

</mx:MenuBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [MenuBarItemRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/MenuBar.html#menuBarItemRenderer) property instead of itemRenderer, which is not defined on the MenuBar class and will most likely throw a compile time error.

If that is not your solution, you'll have to quantify "can't seem to get it working."  Are you seeing a compile errors?  Or runtime error?  Or experiencing unexpected behavior?

Comment: Yes I'm sorry my answer was not clear enough. It is throwing a compile error. Let me test what you have posted and I will get back to you. :)